# Java - Documenting annotations defined in libs using javadocs

Tags: java, annotations, documentation, javadoc

I want to document `javax.ws.rs.Path` annotations used in my rest APIs using javadoc (preferably without any extra doclet). But as it seems, annotations defined in libs are not documented in the javadocs generated using terminal command.

What is the simplest way this can be achieved?

Some more info:

- The said annotation has `@Documented` defined on it.
- libs folder is outside the src folder which is fed to the `-sourcepath` option
- command used : `javadoc -d /Users/home/Desktop/docs -sourcepath ./src/ -subpackages com`

Comment: "What is the simplest..." is asking for opinions, and therefore is off-topic. If you mean to ask just "How", then do that. If you already know some "how", but are looking for an alternative, then explain that in your question, as it's relevant to understanding it.